# Jquery - Find the closest parent having a class name

Tags: jquery

In my application i want to find the closest parent, of a clicked element, having a class name. For that i have the following code with [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. I know it has the functionality to get the closest element with a selector. But here i given a class name as selector like;

```
$(".selectable").click(function(){
    var closest  = $(this).closest('.selectable'); 
});
```

The problem is if the current element and its parent have the same class `.selectable`, it returns the current element itself. But actually i want its parent. For example,

```
<div class="selectable div-1">
    <div class="selectable div-2">
        <!--elements here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example i clicked on `.div-2` div, it returns the `.div-2` itself, not the `.div-1` div. Please dont ask me to remove `.selectable` class from the parent, it's for the functionality.. :-)

Comment: @Satpal Not necessary as like said `closest()` include element itself

Comment: I'm using this:
$(e.target).parents('.select2-container--open').prev().attr('id')

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the first one parent of specific class:

```
$(this).parents('.selectable').first();
```

Answer (score 6):

Then start using `closest()` on the `parent()`

```
$(".selectable").click(function(){
    var closest = $(this).parent().closest('.selectable'); 
});
```

Comment: Quite clever indeed ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.parents()` instead of `.closest()`:

```
 $(this).parents('.selectable');
```

- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks at all ancestors, as well as the originating element, and returns the first match.
- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) looks at all ancestors, and returns all matches.

Comment: The downside is if there is more than one parent with class `selectable`

Comment: that is hard to say unless OP shares the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parents` like below -

```
$(".selectable").click(function(){
    var closest  = $(this).parents('.selectable'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to `return false` in your method in order to avoid bubbling:

```js
$(".selectable").click(function() {
  // var closest  = $(this).parent().closest('.selectable');
  var selectableParentExist = $(this).parents('.selectable').length;

  if (selectableParentExist > 0) {
    var closest = $(this).parents('.selectable');
    alert(closest.attr("id"));
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv" class="selectable div-1">Parent Div
  <div id="selectableDiv" class="selectable div-2">
    <!--elements here-->Selectable Div
  </div>
</div>
```